# Exporting 1 page of form to pdf in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, export-to-pdf

How can I use a macro to export the first page of a form in microsoft access to a pdf?

Currently I can make the selection for page 1 in the export wizard but I want the export to be executed with a button.  When I build an export macro the pdf is a few thousand pages because it is pulling all the records.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you print it with the pdf driver as the printer?

Comment: I had a filter set that was confusing the current record.  Fixed now.  Thank you